# Problems auto-detecting type definitions in .js files with TypeScript

Tags: typescript

TypeScript is documented to auto-detect type definitions from installed npm modules.

For example the type definitions of jQuery are auto-detected quite nicely:

```
$ npm install typescript @types/jquery
$ echo '$("body").text("Hello");' > index.js
$ node_modules/.bin/tsc --allowJs --checkJs --noEmit index.js
# (no errors)
```

### Vue

However Vue's type definitions are not auto-detected, at least when used in JS:

```
$ npm install typescript git+ssh://git@github.com/vuejs/vue.git#ab50e8e1da2f4f944af683252481728485fedf16
$ echo 'new Vue({ el: "body", template: "Hello" });' > index.js
$ node_modules/.bin/tsc --allowJs --checkJs --noEmit index.js
index.js:1:5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Vue'.

1 new Vue({ el: "body", template: "Hello" });
      ~~~
Found 1 error.
```

Workaround: If I explicitly include `node_modules/vue/types/umd.d.ts` as a source file, then it starts working:

```
$ node_modules/.bin/tsc --allowJs --checkJs --noEmit index.js node_modules/vue/types/umd.d.ts
# (no errors)
```

Observation: Vue type definitions appear to be available **in .ts files** if I explicitly import Vue. (Explicitly importing is not an option in .js files.)

```
$ echo 'import Vue from "vue"; new Vue({ el: "body", template: "Hello" });' > index.ts
$ node_modules/.bin/tsc --allowJs --checkJs --noEmit index.ts
# (no errors)
```

(The version of Vue I installed above is a recent developer build that contains a fix for 
https://github.com/vuejs/vue/pull/9912/files which allows Vue to be used in UMD contexts, which I suspect is relevant.)

### Moment.js

**Update:** I've determined there's a bug in Moment's type definitions that prevents it being used from .js files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57263931/604063

Additionally Moment's type definitions are not auto-detected, at least when used in JS:

```
$ npm install typescript moment
$ echo 'document.querySelector("body").textContent = moment().toString();' > index.js
$ node_modules/.bin/tsc --allowJs --checkJs --noEmit index.js
index.js:1:46 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'moment'.

1 document.querySelector("body").textContent = moment().toString();
                                               ~~~~~~
Found 1 error.
```

Workaround: If I create a `moment.shims.d.ts` file with the following content:

```
import moment_func from 'moment';
declare global {
    const moment: typeof moment_func;
}
```

And then compile with this shim, plus the `--esModuleInterop` flag (to make the import in the above shim file be permitted), then it works.

```
$ node_modules/.bin/tsc --allowJs --checkJs --noEmit --esModuleInterop index.js moment.shims.d.ts
# (no errors)
```

Observation: Moment type definitions appear to be available **in .ts files** if I explicitly import Moment. (Explicitly importing is not an option in .js files.)

```
$ echo 'import * as moment from "moment"; document.querySelector("body").textContent = moment().toString();' > index.ts
$ node_modules/.bin/tsc --allowJs --checkJs --noEmit index.ts
```

### Discussion

I think it would be great if I could just `npm install` Vue, Moment, and other JS libraries and have their types available in .js files without having to devise special workarounds for each library.

**Is it actually intended that I be able to use these libraries in .js the way that I'm expecting?**

No? Why not? Could we at least standardize the kind of the workaround to make library types available in .js? (With Vue I had to explicitly include a particular source file and with Moment I needed a custom-written shim file.)

Yes? Then is there perhaps a bug in the type definitions for Vue and Moment that prevent TypeScript's library type auto-detection from picking them up?