# How to typecheck a .js file that uses Moment using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, momentjs

I have a small .js file using Moment intended to be run directly in a browser that I want to be type-checked with the TypeScript compiler:

```
document.querySelector("body").textContent = moment().toString();
```

If I try to typecheck it with `tsc`, the compiler complains it cannot find the declaration for `moment` even though I have the `moment` npm package installed:

```
$ npm install typescript moment
$ node_modules/.bin/tsc --allowJs --checkJs --noEmit index.js
index.js:1:46 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'moment'.

1 document.querySelector("body").textContent = moment().toString();
                                               ~~~~~~
Found 1 error.
```

How do I tell the TypeScript compiler to auto-detect the `moment` global object or to import it explicitly in the JS file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## For moment <= 2.24.0

Create a file `moment.shims.d.ts` with the contents:

```
import moment from '../../node_modules/moment/moment';

export = moment;

export as namespace moment;
```

(Alter the import line to point to your installed version of moment in node_modules.)

Compile this shims file alongside the rest of your TypeScript project.

You may need to enable the `esModuleInterop` option in your `tsconfig.json` or in your call to `tsc --esModuleInterop true`:

```
{
    ...
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "esModuleInterop": true,  // needed by: moment.shims.d.ts
    },
}
```

## For moment > 2.24.0

No special action required, once [this PR](https://github.com/moment/moment/pull/5181) is accepted.

Comment: This works great! It could use one small tweak, though: instead of referencing the full path to the moment.d.ts in the 2.24 shim, you can, for the first line, simply... import moment from "moment"

Answer (score 0):

How are you importing the `moment` package?

I don't get any errors here using require / CommonJS syntax:

```
// index.js

const moment = require("moment")

document.querySelector("body").textContent = moment().toString();
```

Testing that with `tsc --allowJs --checkJs --noEmit src/index.js` gives me no errors.

Now if you want to use ES6 syntax you would do it like:

```
// index.js

import moment from 'moment'

document.querySelector("body").textContent = moment().toString();
```

And add `"esModuleInterop": true` under `compilerOptions` in your tsconfig.json file.

Comment: I'm using moment from a .js file intended to be run directly in a browser, so there is no import.

Comment: Are you using a bundler like maybe Parcel or Webpack? Because these would bundle `moment` inside your web application and you would be able to run it directly in a browser even using `moment` as a library.

Comment: No Webpack or Parcel here. For our production builds there is concatenation and minification but no bundling (of imports or requires). Development builds are run directly, with no transformations at all.

Answer (score 0):

If it is available globally, you can use:

`declare var moment:any`

This tells typescript that moment is declared elsewhere and it should not throw error.

You can also specify type instead of `any` if you want  more strongly typed code

Comment: That will allow you to check an expression like moment() but not a type annotation like /** @type moment.Moment */